# IBM WebSphere Portal & multiple Active Directories with trusted relationship

Tags: active-directory, ldap, websphere-portal

There are two active directory user registrys with trusted relationship, where users of one directory included in the groups of another directory. I need to configure IBM WebSphere Portal 6.1 on WAS7 that he used those related directories. But when federated repository is configured and I am trying to find users via  group there are only those users who are in the same directory as the group. It works like it is independent registrys without trusted relationship.
Is it possible to configure portal server that he understood the trusted relationship of user registrys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was the usage of Global LDAP search port 3268 (3269) instead of default LDAP ports 389(636) and standalone repository.

Answer (score 0):

Enable following referrals for both WAS security settings and WIM. You will have to edit security.xml and wimconfig.xml manually to accomplish all required changes.